# Trying to do a SQL Merge statement, but it errors

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, composite-key

I've got a stored procedure that accepts batches of product info. For each product, either insert it into the DB or Update it, if it already exists.

A product is defined by a composite key -> `ProductCompanyId` (where the product came from) and a `ProductId` (the unique Id, per company).

I'm trying to do a `MERGE` query. It works perfectly, until the batch has the same composite key in it more than once.

For example, lets imagine I have 10 products. 2 of these have the same comp-keys but different prices.

I thought the first 'row' would be inserted, with the 2nd row being an update.

Here [is some FULL REPO sql code](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/5998399) to show you what I've done.

It's far too hard to try and make sure there's only unique composite key's per batch. So, is there anything I can do?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 .. so I'm not sure if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using @MergeData directly as source of your `MERGE` statement, you could (should) rewrite it to use subquery or CTE that will filter duplicate rows and choose the correct one to be used in `MERGE`

```
WITH CTE_MergeData AS 
(
    SELECT *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCompanyId, ProductId ORDER BY  ProductId DESC) RN --find some better order
    FROM @MergeData
)
MERGE INTO @SomeTable T
    USING (SELECT * FROM CTE_MergeData WHERE RN = 1) S
    ON T.ProductCompanyId = S.ProductCompanyId AND T.ProductId = S.ProductId
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
        SET T.Name = S.Name,
            T.Price = S.Price
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ProductCompanyId, ProductId, Name, Price)
        VALUES (S.ProductCompanyId, S.ProductId, S.Name, S.Price)
    OUTPUT S.ProductCompanyId, S.ProductId, Inserted.Id INTO @MergeProductsResults;
```

Comment: Ha brilliant! of course :) filter unique's BEFORE I Merge on it. Woot!